# Wrong Workspace Type Error with arcpy.ChangeVersion

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

When using arcpy.ChangeVersion_management() on a feature class inside of a feature dataset, I get ERROR 000301: Workspace is of the wrong type.

Posts addressing the same error stemming from arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management() suggest verifying the version name formatting. I have done that but it hasn't helped.
I am currently providing the username.versionName all in capital.
It works for a feature class outside of the feature dataset (the feature is part of a geometric network).
I have also tried including the feature dataset name in the feature path to no avail.
On ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1

Comment: Default version is a property of a connection, not a feature dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Default version'? Using the CURRENT map in ArcmMap, I can change the version of a feature class with acrpy.ChangeVersion_management('feature_class_outside_featureDataset', 'TRANSACRIONAL', 'username.versionName'). Just changing the feature from outside to inside a feature dataset breaks it. How can I handle that?

Comment: Ahh, that's the other side of the coin. Once inside a feature dataset, all feature classes must have the same version (they're edited as one), so you must specify the FDS.